# How to programmatically take a screenshot on Android?

Tags: android, screenshot

How can I take a screenshot of a selected area of phone-screen not by any program but from code?

Comment: Not from emulator. 
I need to make screenshot of part of my programm, and do smth with it in the same programm.

Comment: Another good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10296881/439171

Comment: Here's how http://hackerseve.com/android-save-view-as-image-and-share-externally/

Answer (score 493, accepted):

Here is the code that allowed my screenshot to be stored on an SD card and used later for whatever your needs are:

First, you need to add a proper permission to save the file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And this is the code (running in an Activity):

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is how you can open the recently generated image:

```
private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If you want to use this on fragment view then use:

```
View v1 = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

instead of

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

on **takeScreenshot()** function

**Note**:

This solution doesn't work if your dialog contains a surface view. For details please check the answer to the following question:

[Android Take Screenshot of Surface View Shows Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen)

Comment: What happened if background image of captured view is partly transparent..? In my case background color is captured too.. Do u have idea how not to capture other things below, let's say, half-transparent view? 10q

Comment: It worked but i am passing the root view of existing image view but the whole activity view is getting saved in sdcard.Please help i am very close.I want to save the snap shot of image not the whole view.

Comment: Ewoks: I had the same problem, it rendered black text over black background because this method won't draw the background (as you don't have access to those views. I found a solution to, at least, use the themed background (I'll post that as another answer)

Comment: @xamar i am strucked at this... not able to take the screen shot of the specified view ( the ImageView)

Comment: this worked for me but i have having problem with javaoutofmemory exception. because i do not clear the cache how do i go about clearing the cache

Comment: Hi, Can you describe what is mCurrentUrlMask? I have tried this code but it is always giving me NullPointerException at Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache()), Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong.? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @MiteshSardhara `mCurrentUrlMask` must be a `View` since is the unique class in the Android API that has the `getRootView()` method. Probably is a view in the UI.

Comment: b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, new BufferedOutputStream( fout ));It's better to wrap the FileOutputStream with a BufferedStream:

Comment: I'm getting Nullpointerexception problem here View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();    i have declared mCurrentUrlMask as a view but how am i supposed to initialize that view, what is supposed to be in that view, please help

Comment: Can you please tell me what is, mCurrentUrlMask?

Comment: Try this : 
View v1=  findViewById(R.id.LayoutID); 
 v1.getRootView();

Comment: mCurrentUrlMask is a view that the original poster had declared elsewhere in his code. It does not serve any purpose here other than to have getRootView() called on it. The important part is that v1 is the view that will have its image taken so as long as that is the main view you should be ok. If your xml has a LinearLayout called mainLinearLayout then you could replace the code with
v1 = (LinearLayout)findViewByID(R.id.mainLinearLayout);
And as long as the mainLinearLayout is both visible and inside the screen it will have its image taken, otherwise you need to inflate/measure it yourself.

Comment: Insted of `View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();` I have used `View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();` and it works for me.

Comment: for anybody else who is wondering same, [here you can go..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067586/how-to-capture-the-android-device-screen-content/8504958#8504958)

Comment: I am using the same code to take screen shot in a loop, this code is only generating 13-14 images per second whereas i need 24-25 images per second so after that i will be able to create a video.

Comment: If you get `EACCES (Permission denied)` error, add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: What if my view is scrollview? will it also capture content that isn't visible? Is there a way to get whole data?

Comment: Do not forget to recycle bitmap to avoid MEMORY LEAK!
   public static void recycleInBackground(final Bitmap bitmapToRecycle)
 {
  if(bitmapToRecycle==null || bitmapToRecycle.isRecycled())
  {
   return;
  }

  new Thread(new Runnable()
  {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
    bitmapToRecycle.recycle();
   }
  });
 }

Comment: does the phone need to be rooted to do this?

Comment: This method does not work in all cases. For example it fails to capture a Google Maps (MapView v2) or a dialog. (It's probably because map uses glsurfaceview).

Comment: can you store the image in the gallery? this works fine but opening the image from other applications is very difficult since the image is not stored in the gallery section.

Comment: Does this work when the app is in the background as well?

Comment: This answer takes a screenshot of just the app - not the "phone screen" as asked in the question - or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: This will not take snapshot of status bar. How can i Include it also?

Comment: it's not good for real time when you want to record it in a video

Comment: i want current any screen capture screenshot like system screenshot  during start mobile . so please let me know how is there –

Comment: The setDrawingCache() method is deprecated in API 28. Check my answer which shows how to use the new API for saving screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51875893/2380518

Comment: The elevation is skipped !!

Comment: How can I take screenshots along with status bar? I only able to take screenshots of my app only .I want to take screenshots with tame anddate with battry status ,which is shown on the top of app in status bar.

Comment: Does your solution also capture scrollable hidden area? i.e. webview showing long list of items.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to take the screenshot of the fragment view. So I used this line instead (in the fragments class):    View v1 = this.getView();

Comment: Also, do not forget to tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
immediately available to the user in the gallery (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144840/how-can-i-refresh-the-gallery-after-i-inserted-an-image-in-android)

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, no.

Comment: For this to work in recent versions of Android, you'll have to use `getFilesDir()` instead of external storage and use FileProvider to share the image: https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0

Comment: As DrawCache is now deprecated, it is recommended to use: "view.drawToBitmap()"

Answer (score 160):

Call this method, passing in the outer most ViewGroup that you want a screen shot of:

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: This is seems to be cleaner code than the accepted answer.  Does it perform as well?

Comment: I've used it for a while in a few different apps and haven't had any issues.

Comment: If you want to get a screenshot of the phone, where your app is in the background, what do you pass as the `view`?`

Comment: Passing `getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()` as the view results in taking a screenshot of just the app - not the screen.

Comment: This answer takes a screenshot of just the app - not the "phone screen" as asked in the question - or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka No, it's not for taking a screenshot no matter in which app you are. For this, there is a special API, but I can't find out how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32513379/878126

Comment: when i am trying this its generating screen shot with bad quality. how can i overcome this?

Comment: There's a small issue, this does not seem to capture the activity background color. Any ideas?

Comment: to take a screen shot of Screen Use getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView() but it requires api 21

Comment: In my case I have a WebView in which I load an animating image url. After creating bitmap, it captures everything except the animating objects. Can we do something for that?

Comment: i want current any screen capture screenshot during start mobile  so please let me know how is there –

Comment: Crazy that this solution still works at 2020, without asking for permission, dealing with any advanced configuration or api limitations. You surprised me Android.

Comment: Android 11, 2022 - works fine.

Comment: For anyone looking for a detailed answer - https://ssaurel.medium.com/taking-a-screenshot-programmatically-in-android-apps-67619cb80bf8

Comment: how do we send this bitmap object to whatsapp url call?

Answer (score 44):

**Note: works only for rooted phone**

Programmatically, you can run `adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png` as below

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor();
```

then read `img.png` as `Bitmap` and use as your wish.

Comment: Is it need root access?

Comment: Yes you need root access. Please check the Note at the heading

Comment: Hi, I got a `System.err : java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null `, my device is android 5.0

Comment: @Eddy It depends on your device

Comment: Is there a way to read the output directly without saving the result into file then reading it again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914035

Comment: @YazanWYusuf I don't know any way a process will directly communicate with our application. Will check and get back to you on this.

Comment: `Error opening file: img.png (Read-only file system)`. lol root access.

Answer (score 31):

**No root permission** or **no big coding** is required for this method.

---

On adb shell using below command you can take screen shot.

```
input keyevent 120
```

This command does not required any root permission so same you can perform from java code of android application also.

```
Process process;
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent 120");
```

More about keyevent code in android see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Here we have used.  **KEYCODE_SYSRQ** its value is 120 and used for System Request / Print Screen key.

---

As CJBS said, The output picture will be saved in **/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots**

Comment: The output picture will be saved here: `/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots`

Comment: does it require root permission??

Comment: @Taranmeet No it does not require root permission

Comment: will it works on marshmallow ? or will it works in service background @JeegarPatel

Comment: not worked programmatically, but works from shell. Tried with nougat.

Comment: `su -c "input keyevent 120"` is ok!!

Comment: It is working from terminal but not programmatically..Any idea...?

Comment: It doesn't work on marshmallow too. and doesn't even throw an exception !

Comment: Executing `input keyevent ...` requires root

Comment: I have used this code 4-5 years ago in my android app and it was working. I think in latest version of android input keyevent may require root permission or any other permission. Can someone confirm on this so we can update answer here.

Answer (score 20):

As a reference, one way to capture the screen (and not just your app activity) is to capture the **framebuffer** (device /dev/graphics/fb0). To do this you must either have root privileges or your app must be an app with [signature permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel) ("A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission") - which is very unlikely unless you compiled your own ROM.

Each framebuffer capture, from a couple of devices I have tested, contained **exactly** one screenshot. People have reported it to contain more, I guess it depends on the frame/display size.

I tried to read the framebuffer continuously but it seems to return for a fixed amount of bytes read. In my case that is (3 410 432) bytes, which is enough to store a display frame of 854*480 RGBA (3 279 360 bytes). Yes, the frame, in binary, outputted from fb0 is **RGBA** in my device. This will most likely depend from device to device. This will be important for you to decode it =)

In my device **/dev/graphics/fb0** permissions are so that only root and users from group graphics can read the fb0.

**graphics** is a restricted group so you will probably only access fb0 with a rooted phone using su command.

Android apps have the **user id (uid) = app_##** and **group id (guid) = app_##** .

**adb shell** has **uid = shell** and **guid = shell**, which has much more permissions than an app. You can actually check those permissions at /system/permissions/platform.xml

This means you will be able to read fb0 in the adb shell without root but you will not read it within the app without root.

Also, giving READ_FRAME_BUFFER and/or ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER permissions on AndroidManifest.xml will do nothing for a regular app because these will only work for '**signature**' apps.

Also check this **[closed thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3067586/1085483)** for more details.

Comment: This works (worked?) on some phones, but note that GPU based phones don't necessarily provide a linear framebuffer to the applications processor.

Answer (score 19):

Mualig answer is very good, but I had the same problem Ewoks describes, I'm not getting the background. So sometimes is good enough and sometimes I get black text over black background (depending on the theme).

This solution is heavily based in Mualig code and the code I've found in Robotium. I'm discarding the use of drawing cache by calling directly to the draw method. Before that I'll try to get the background drawable from current activity to draw it first.

```
// Some constants
final static String SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/screenshots/";

// Get device dimmensions
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

// Get root view
View view = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();

// Create the bitmap to use to draw the screenshot
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.x, size.y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

// Get current theme to know which background to use
final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
final Theme theme = activity.getTheme();
final TypedArray ta = theme
    .obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.windowBackground });
final int res = ta.getResourceId(0, 0);
final Drawable background = activity.getResources().getDrawable(res);

// Draw background
background.draw(canvas);

// Draw views
view.draw(canvas);

// Save the screenshot to the file system
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    final File sddir = new File(SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS);
    if (!sddir.exists()) {
        sddir.mkdirs();
    }
    fos = new FileOutputStream(SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS
            + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    if (fos != null) {
        if (!bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Compress/Write failed");
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have a listview  with android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" in my activity , and I use this code to screenshot , I still got a black background , because I found that background that get from theme is black , how can I deal with this listview?

Comment: Activity activity = getCurrentActivity giving Eroor undefined method.

Answer (score 19):

```
private void captureScreen() {
    View v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "SCREEN"
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Add the permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

For Supporting **Marshmallow** or above versions, please add the below code in the activity onCreate method

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},00);
```

Comment: Requires : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: This answer takes a screenshot of just the app - not the "phone screen" as asked in the question - or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What about If I need screenshot of an item of listview?

Comment: i want to capture in from adapter any idea how can i do it?

Comment: same concept applied :D

Answer (score 18):

My solution is:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(Context context, View v) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
    v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.widthPixels, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.heightPixels, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
            v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    v.draw(c);

    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

and

```
public void takeScreen() {
    Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.loadBitmapFromView(this, view); //get Bitmap from the view
    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "screen_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg";
    File imageFile = new File(mPath);
    OutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
        fout.flush();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        fout.close();
    }
}
```

Images are saved in the external storage folder.

Comment: You should close the FileOutputStream in a finally block. If you encounter an exception now the stream will not be closed.

Comment: What's the `view` you're passing to `ImageUtils.loadBitmapFromView(this, view)`?

Comment: why do you use v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight()); ? Doesn't that change the view (v) ?

Answer (score 14):

You can try the following library:
http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/
Android Screenshot Library (ASL) enables to programmatically capture screenshots from Android devices without requirement of having root access privileges. Instead, ASL utilizes a native service running in the background, started via the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) once per device boot.

Comment: I tried this.but it takes screenshot of the running app alone. Its cant help if i want to take screenshot of the homescreen. do you how to take screenshot of the homescreen withthat code?

Comment: @Janardhanan.S: This is what the question is asking for. Can you elaborate with a new answer instead of asking a separate question.

Comment: @Kuba i installed this app but it shows native service not found. Help me please.

Comment: Same Problem with me.. "Native Service Not Running!!"

Comment: Same with me "Native Service Not Running!!".... can anybody add the help text here?

Comment: same here! "Native Service Not Running!!" and in their latest version 1.2 they use API LEVEL 19 classes, like Socket for example.

Comment: need to enable the service via pc each times the phone restart.  :(

Answer (score 13):

Based on the answer of @JustinMorris above and @NiravDangi here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504958/2232148 we must take the background and foreground of a view and assemble them like this:

```
public static Bitmap takeScreenshot(View view, Bitmap.Config quality) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), quality);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Drawable backgroundDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (backgroundDrawable != null) {
        backgroundDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

The quality parameter takes a constant of Bitmap.Config, typically either `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` or `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`.

Comment: drawing canvas with white color in case background is null did the trick for me. Thanks Oliver

Answer (score 11):

Most of the answers for this question use the the `Canvas` drawing method or drawing cache method. However, the [`View.setDrawingCache()` method is deprecated in API 28](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean)). Currently the recommended API for making screenshots is the [`PixelCopy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy) class available from API 24 (but the methods which accept `Window` parameter are available from API 26 == Android 8.0 Oreo). Here is a sample Kotlin code for retrieving a `Bitmap`:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun saveScreenshot(view: View) {
    (view.context as Activity).window?.let { window ->
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val locationOfViewInWindow = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationInWindow(locationOfViewInWindow)
        try {
            PixelCopy.request(window, Rect(locationOfViewInWindow[0], locationOfViewInWindow[1], locationOfViewInWindow[0] + view.width, locationOfViewInWindow[1] + view.height), bitmap, { copyResult ->
                if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                    saveBitmap(bitmap)
                }
                // possible to handle other result codes ...
            }, Handler())
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            // PixelCopy may throw IllegalArgumentException, make sure to handle it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with PixelCopy over the drawingCache solution is, that it seems to only capture visible pixel. the rest is black for me. So it is not possible to share stuff which is scrollable and is partly out of the frame. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: You are right. Similarly it can cause a problem if another View is shown above the View I want to screenshot (e. g. when the drawer is opened). In these cases I just use the old Canvas method :(

Comment: Is it possible to take screenshot on any running app using PixelCopy?

Comment: @AmirRezaei It's used for the current app only, of course. For others, there is a different way...

Answer (score 9):

```
public class ScreenShotActivity extends Activity{

private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private Bitmap myBitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            //take screenshot
            myBitmap = captureScreen(relativeLayout);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screenshot captured..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                if(myBitmap!=null){
                    //save image to SD card
                    saveImage(myBitmap);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screenshot saved..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}

public static Bitmap captureScreen(View v) {

    Bitmap screenshot = null;
    try {

        if(v!=null) {

            screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),v.getMeasuredHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(screenshot);
            v.draw(canvas);
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ScreenShotActivity", "Failed to capture screenshot because:" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return screenshot;
}

public static void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException{

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.png");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
}

}
```

**ADD PERMISSION**

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> ```

Comment: This answer takes a screenshot of just the app - not the "phone screen" as asked in the question - or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You can try to do something like this,

Getting a bitmap cache from a layout or a view by doing something like
First you gotta `setDrawingCacheEnabled` to a layout(a linearlayout or relativelayout, or a view)

then

```
Bitmap bm = layout.getDrawingCache()
```

Then you do whatever you want with the bitmap. Either turning it into an image file, or send the bitmap's uri to somewhere else.

Comment: This is the best method if it is your app that you are writing to a bitmap. Also, beware of methods which have delays before taking the cache... like Notify...() for list views.

Comment: Not just that. The layout must be displayed on the screen first. It's the "cache" you're getting afterall. Tried hiding the view and taking screenshots in the background(in theory), but it didn't work.

Comment: By far more efficient than other solutions

Answer (score 8):

Short way is

```
FrameLayout layDraw = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layDraw); /*Your root view to be part of screenshot*/
layDraw.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmp = layDraw.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 7):

I have created a simple library that takes a screenshot from a `View` and either gives you a Bitmap object or saves it directly to any path you want

https://github.com/abdallahalaraby/Blink

Comment: Does it requires rooted phone ?

Comment: No rooting required :)

Comment: In usage u mentioned `Screenshot.takeScreenshot(view, mPath); imageView.setImageBitmap(Screenshot.getBitmapScreenshot(view, mPath)); ` How to get view of current activity. I dont want to use the id of the xml.

Comment: use `takeScreenshotForScreen()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

For those who want to capture a GLSurfaceView, the getDrawingCache or drawing to canvas method won't work.

You have to read the content of the OpenGL framebuffer after the frame has been rendered. There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514149/capture-screen-of-glsurfaceview-to-bitmap)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to take screenshot from `fragment`  than follow this:

1. Override  `onCreateView()`:

   ```
            @Override
           public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               // Inflate the layout for this fragment
               View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
               mView = view;
           }
   ```
2. Logic for taking screenshot:

   ```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View view =  mView.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
         shareScreenShotM(view, (NestedScrollView) view); 
    }
   ```
3. method `shareScreenShotM)()`:

   ```
   public void shareScreenShotM(View view, NestedScrollView scrollView){

        bm = takeScreenShot(view,scrollView);  //method to take screenshot
       File file = savePic(bm);  // method to save screenshot in phone.
       }
   ```
4. method takeScreenShot():

   ```
            public Bitmap takeScreenShot(View u, NestedScrollView z){

               u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
               int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
               int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

               Log.d("yoheight",""+ totalHeight);
               Log.d("yowidth",""+ totalWidth);
               u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
               u.buildDrawingCache();
               Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
               u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
               u.destroyDrawingCache();
                return b;
           }
   ```
5. method savePic():

   ```
    public static File savePic(Bitmap bm){

           ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File sdCardDirectory =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Foldername");

          if (!sdCardDirectory.exists()) {
               sdCardDirectory.mkdirs();
         }
          //  File file = new File(dir, fileName);
         try {
            file = new File(sdCardDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
               .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
           file.createNewFile();
           new FileOutputStream(file).write(bytes.toByteArray());
           Log.d("Fabsolute", "File Saved::--->" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.d("Sabsolute", "File Saved::--->" + sdCardDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return file;
      }
   ```

For activity you can simply use `View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();` instead of `mView`

Answer (score 5):

Just extending taraloca's answer. You must add followings lines to make it work. **I have made the image name static. Please ensure you use taraloca's timestamp variable incase you need dynamic image name.**

```
    // Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

private void verifyStoragePermissions() {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }else{
        takeScreenshot();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
            takeScreenshot();
        }
    }
}
```

And in the AndroidManifest.xml file following entries are must:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

Answer (score 4):

**For Full Page Scrolling Screenshot**

If you want to capture a full View screenshot (Which contains a scrollview or so) then have a check at this library

> https://github.com/peter1492/LongScreenshot

All you have to do is import the Gradel, and create an object of BigScreenshot

`BigScreenshot longScreenshot = new BigScreenshot(this, x, y);`

A callback will be received with the bitmap of the Screenshots taken while automatically scrolling through the screen view group and at the end assembled together.

`@Override  public void getScreenshot(Bitmap bitmap) {}`

Which can be saved to the gallery or whatsoever usage is necessary their after

Answer (score 3):

**For system applications only!**

```
Process process;
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screencap -p " + outputPath);
process.waitFor();
```

Note: System applications don't need to run "su" to execute this command.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter view is the root layout object.

```
public static Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    if (view.getWidth() > 0 && view.getHeight() > 0) {
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                        view.draw(canvas);
                    }
                    return bitmap;
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

From Android 11 (API level 30) you can take screen shot with the accessibility service:

[takeScreenshot](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#takeScreenshot(int,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.TakeScreenshotCallback)) - Takes a screenshot of the specified display and returns it via an AccessibilityService.ScreenshotResult.

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin**

```
    private fun screenShot() {
          try {
            val mPath: String = this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()
              .toString() + "/temp" + ".png" 
            // create bitmap screenshot
            val v1: View = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()
            v1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.drawingCache)
            v1.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
            val imageFile = File(mPath)
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
            val quality = 100
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream)
            outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()
        
            //or you can share to test the method fast
            val uriPath =
              FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".sharing.provider", imageFile)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.clipData = ClipData.newRawUri("", uriPath)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriPath)
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sharing to..."))
          } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
          }
        }
```

**Java**

```
  private void screenShot() {
    try {
      String mPath = this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/temp" + ".png";
      // create bitmap screenshot
      View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
      v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
      v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

      File imageFile = new File(mPath);
      FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
      int quality = 100;
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
      outputStream.flush();
      outputStream.close();

      //or you can share to test the method fast

      Uri uriPath = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".sharing.provider", imageFile);
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      intent.setType("image/*");
      intent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", uriPath));
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriPath);
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sharing to..."));

    } catch (Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take screenshot of a view in android.

```
public static Bitmap getViewBitmap(View v) {
    v.clearFocus();
    v.setPressed(false);

    boolean willNotCache = v.willNotCacheDrawing();
    v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);

    int color = v.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
    v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0);

    if (color != 0) {
        v.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
    v.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap cacheBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
    if (cacheBitmap == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cacheBitmap);

    v.destroyDrawingCache();
    v.setWillNotCacheDrawing(willNotCache);
    v.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(color);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture screenshot of a *View*, use `View::drawToBitmap` extension function:

```kotlin
val bitmap = myTargetView.drawToBitmap(/*Optional:*/ Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
```

Only make sure to use the **-ktx** version of [AndroidX Core](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) library:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0")
```

I've already answered a similar question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69223764/8583692).

Comment: it's also available in 1.2.0 version, glad I dont need to upgrade

Answer (score -2):

If you want to capture a view or layout like `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` etc.

Just use the code:

```
LinearLayout llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutMain);
Bitmap bm = loadBitmapFromView(llMain);
```

now you can save this bitmap on device storage by :

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Screen Shots/");
f.mkdir();
String extStorageDirectory = f.toString();
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "my new screen shot");
pathOfImage = file.getAbsolutePath();
try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved at "+f.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    addImageGallery(file);
    //mail.setEnabled(true);
    flag=true;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
try {
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```