# Convert text to PDF

Tags: android, pdf-generation, pdf-writer

I am trying to create a PDF file by inserting some text into it with a proper structure in Android.

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("urgentz.pdf"));
doc.open();
Image image = Image.getInstance ("urgentzImageahslkdhaosd.jpg");
doc.add(new Paragraph("Your text blah bleh"));
doc.add(image);               
doc.close();
```

The above code does not work.

Comment: Here is a tutorial of how to Convert Text to PDF in Java. Hope this helps.

http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/TextToPDF.shtml

Comment: – iKiar Its not working for android. It gives error in importing PDF Reader

Comment: Did you properly add all of the .jar files to your project? (Check your Java Build Path)

Comment: What is the error? Can you edit your question and add the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing stacktrace I can only guess what's wrong. You might find these questions useful:

- [How to create PDFs in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2499960/262462)
- [how to Generate Pdf File with Image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6674059/262462)

Some ideas:

1. Check File paths. You have specified only filenames to pdf and image without any paths. Use something like `/mnt/sdcard/<YourFolderHere>/somefile.pdf` and make sure you have defined `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in AndroidManifest.xml
2. Use [droidText](http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/) instead of `iText`
3. Try another PDF Writer library http://coderesearchlabs.com/androidpdfwriter/