# how i generate a pdf with Android

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I have this problem I'm developing an app and I need that it can generate pdf that it containing information taken from the database and from the same canvas can someone help me?

Comment: This can help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674059/how-to-generate-pdf-file-with-image-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple : use [iTextG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextg/)

This is [the Android/GAE port of iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/product/itextg).

Comment: thank but is not free and i prefer a good tutorial can you help me?

Comment: Then go to : http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/

Comment: Follow this example : (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html)