# How to edit or generate a PDF in Android SDK

Tags: android, html, pdf, android-droidtext

I'm working in an app, and I need which the app can generate a PDF file with the app data saved in XML's.
I need make this in one of two ways, but I don't know how, the ways are:

- Generate a PDF from a existing HTML
- Edit an existing PDF and add text.

I don't know how iText or droidText can help me.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

How about having a look at this StackOverflow post?

[Android - how to convert html to pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669083/android-how-to-convert-html-to-pdf)

I'm guessing your question requires a similar, if not exactly identical approach.

(By the way, performing a Google search on "generate PDF from HTML android" yielded 305,000,000 other results, many of which seem legitimate answers on your question...)

Comment: Well, I'm searching a lot for an answer. All the answers are about use iText. I don't want create a new PDF, only needs edit a PDF or generate one from HTML. I don't know how take the solution for these answer. I'm new in Android.

Comment: What's the difference between creating a new PDF and generating one from HTML? The answer link contains this link (http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html) to an article that explains in great detail how to use iText to create a PDF file on Android. You should be able to take the information out of your XML files in your app and generate a PDF file, no? If not, please explain why not as that might help people to help you...