# Conversion of HTML page into pdf file in Android

Tags: android, itext

We have to generate pdf file using html file. 
For e.g. we have file "mypage.html" we have to show all page data as it is in pdf file. 
Every time in application we will receive new html pages & we have to show as it is in pdf file.
Can we know how to do this by using iText or any third party libraries ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - how to convert html to pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669083/android-how-to-convert-html-to-pdf)

Comment: @MocialovBoris link explains iText & other libraries are used to create the PDF file in android. But our requirement is we have to show the pdf file exactly like we have html page at our side.

Comment: @MocialovBoris for e.g Html page contains "headers, body, images, footer" same kind of data with "colors, fonts" we have show in pdf file.