# Html to PDF using PdfDocument

Tags: android

I am trying  to generate a PDF from a HTML string using PdfDocument:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html

String example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I know how to generate a PDF files from a WebView, but not from a string HTML. How i do this? 
I don't found in stackoverflow.com or Google how do this with the native class PDFDOCUMENT

Comment: Load the HTML into a `WebView`, via `loadData()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I do not want to upload a web view, i need print a object java in a pdf...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - how to convert html to pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669083/android-how-to-convert-html-to-pdf)

Comment: Not, i need used the PdfDocument native, not itext

Answer (score 6):

This [class](https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java) does what you are looking for.

But to compile, it must be in package ".../java/android/print/"

Here is a simple code example :

```
PdfConverter converter = PdfConverter.getInstance();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "file.pdf");
String htmlString = "<html><body><p>WHITE (default)</p></body></html>";
converter.convert(getContext(), htmlString, file);
// By now the pdf has been printed in the file.
```

Answer (score 1):

react-native-html-to-pdf works great and has **zero** iText dependencies.

https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf

- Renders SVG `<svg>` ( Very easy to reuse svg code [from Google Material Icons](https://material.io/icons/) in an HTML document )
- Renders `<img />` using base64 or local files ( make sure you close the img tag )
- **CSS** style works great.
- You can Control page breaks from your HTML.

  `<p style="page-break-before: always;" />`

I forked it and added page size and orientation options to Android.  I plan to do the same to iOS but it currently has width and height options that can accomplish this same thing.

This is a cross-platform Android and iOS React Native library.

Look in the Android directory if you just need the Java.

Comment: Not sure where you see that it has zero iText dependencies.  It says "The android module pulls in iText to convert html to pdf. A license is required for commercial use."

Comment: The README is out of date.  Read the Java source instead. 
 https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java

Comment: See commit comment that "iText has been removed".  https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf/commit/5d4092b149f25e85117c8060b1d4968f35829407