# android pdf writer

Tags: android, pdf

I need to add/remove bookmarks/annotation to a pdf on an Android App. Is there a third party library for that? From what I've found iText but it isn't ported to Android and none of the open source pdf viewers have this feature.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://apwlibrary.svn.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this answer helpful:
[How to create PDFs in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-android-sdk)

Apparently you should still be able to use iText for your needs.