# Does Adobe have an Android SDK or API for their PDF reader?

Tags: android

I want to be able to display local PDF files in a View within our app.  (running on a tablet under Android 4.03)    Currently we install AdobeReader.apk along with our app and launch it with an Intent. (our devices are shipped with our software preinstalled)    But that means it runs separately and we have no programmatic control over it (for example, an image that's too big to fit on the screen will force the user to pan around -  I'd rather have it shrunk to fit a specified size.)

So does Adobe offer an SDK for Android?    If not, are there robust alternatives?   I've looked at a few third-party ones but they seemed unfinished and not-ready-for-prime-time or they have open licensing issues that would conflict with our commercial/industrial application.

(I know this question has been asked before but maybe something new has emerged since last time it was asked)

Comment: I don't think they do, just use another PDF reader? I'm sure some indie app would implement the functionality for you

Comment: Have you tried loading the PDF in a `WebView`?

Comment: Have you looked at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-android-sdk?lq=1)

Comment: He doesn't look for a library to *create* PDFs, but to *render* them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's the [Adobe® Reader Mobile SDK](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/readermobile.html), as user [KPath001 already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11420817/1467115), but you have to directly contact Adobe for more pricing/licensing information.

The [Foxit Embedded PDF SDK](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/embedded/) would be another commercial possibility, if their [pricing](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/embedded/pricing.php) doesn't blow your budget.

Other commercial libraries (without pricing information available online) are:

- [Qoppa qPDF Toolkit](http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/)
- [PDFTron Mobile PDF SDK™](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/android_pdf_library.html)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this or what?
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/readermobile.html

Check this stack question [How to create PDFs in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-android-sdk) it might help

Comment: Adobe Reader Mobile 9 SDK is a set of C++ API's.   I'm not sure now to embed them in Dalvik/Android.   Regarding the second link -  I just want to display PDF files, not create them.