# is it possible to scroll (move) pdf programatically?

Tags: android

I have one PDF file and give some annotation on them. Now move PDF automatically base on instruction like on click of view.
I want scroll PDF in particular position.

Answer (score 0):

Just go on this link i hope solve your query.
PDF Annotation on customization.

[Does Adobe have an Android SDK or API for their PDF reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420700/does-adobe-have-an-android-sdk-or-api-for-their-pdf-reader)

Thank You.