# Flash to Android app, how to use "php" without internet?

Tags: php, android, flash, pdf, apk

I want to make an Android app, using Flash and Adobe AIR. Although I've made a lot of online Flash games, I've never used export to Android app (.apk).

The app won't be in the Playstore. I will install it on 3 tablets and use them. The app is onyl ment for these 3 tablets. It's for some kind of training.

Before I start I would like to know if this function is possible:

The app is some sort of quiz and at the end I would like to save the score and the given answers on a PDF on the tablet itself. I've used output to PDF before, but then I would need PHP... how would I do that using Flash and making an Android app? This function should also work when the tablet not connected to the internet.

Comment: Take look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-67096d2612dea547bfa-8000.html - Export application with embedded AIR runtime Select this option if you want to embed the AIR runtime within the APK file while exporting the application package. Users can then run the application even on a device that does not have AIR already installed on it.

Comment: what is the reason you want to use flash/adobe air on android?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:
http://phpforandroid.net/

"SL4A (Android Scripting Environment) is a Google-mantained project which “brings scripting languages to Android by allowing you to edit and execute scripts and interactive interpreters directly on the Android device”."

Comment: Thnx! Sounds great, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I would steer away from using PHP on the tablet itself. It is needlesly complicated to install an extra programming language on the machine, just to create a PDF!

For creating PDF's I would refer you [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-android-sdk), (and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-android-sdk/4565602#4565602)) which lists some methods of creating PDF's offline.

For exporting the flash, you can, as @g00dy says, use flex<sup>1</sup>, but just like the "install PHP for PDF creation" this *could be* a bit overkill for a quiz. I'm not saying that it is, if you have a perfect and complete flash ready you can export it might be worth trying it, but when you have to start building yet, you might just want to go native?

<sup>1) http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-67096d2612dea547bfa-8000.html</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at the links. Wihtout using internet is necessary though. 

I have to start building yet, but I think it's cheaper/faster to use Flash than asking a native programmer.

Comment: You should known that if you convert your flash to an .apk, you still have no easy method (as far as I know) to call some php function trough the link @Akdr posted. I don't see how you can use that setup in any meaningfull way for your usecase. In the end, you would need to do some manual programming to call your function. And if you do, It might be easier to just use some java library /method to generate PDF's, then to install some sort of PHP server.