# Create a pdf in android with the entire listview items. (Listview has items when scrolled)

Tags: android

I have to create a pdf with the entire listview items. 
I found code in 
to create pdf file.
I could not find the pdf creating application which could copy the entire UI or say in my case the entire listview into the pdf. If anybody could suggest what could be done in this case I would be grateful.

Thanks,
Android developer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020059/converting-the-entire-listview-items-children-to-bitmap ask once

Answer (score 0):

see the below links you can get some ideas

credits to [kape123](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4565602/1937802)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/ (library)

http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPDF/article.html (tutorial)

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/image.html (images tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done.

To create a pdf from a view, as far as I know, the view must be inflated. A ListView recycles its views so not all of the list items exist at one time.

I'm facing the same problem and am resorting to drawing on the canvas myself. I plan on drawing a table on the canvas and then iterating over the list writing each item to the canvas if there's room (creating a new page with table if not).

If there's a simpler solution, someone feel free to suggest it... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height value for your main Layout much higher than your screen Size.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="10000dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

And then place a Layout on that main Layout (on this example with 10000dp, i don't know what the limit is)

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layoutForYourListview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You can now place everything you want on this layout. But don't forget to set the height value of your items specially for your ListView to wrap_content. If you do this your whole ListView will be there and you can create your PDF file with the layoutForYourListview.  Maybe you can even calculate the heights of the items, I'm new in Programming.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/imyourlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```