# Converting the entire listview items (children) to bitmap

Tags: android, android-listview

I have to create the bitmaps for entire listview items; currently I am following this approach:

`To capture the listview individual items I have the below code:`

```
ListView listview = shoppingItemList;
        BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) listview.getAdapter();
        int itemscount = adapter.getCount();
        int allitemsheight = 0;
        List<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        System.out.println("In getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap.......");
        for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {

            View childView = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);            childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            childView.measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    childView.getMeasuredHeight());
            // childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            childView.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(childView.getDrawingCache());
            bmps.add(b);
            childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            allitemsheight += childView.getMeasuredHeight();

        }
```

The problem I am facing is that:
My application exits without logging any error after childView.measure...
Can anyone please help me figuring out what exactly is the issue.

Thanks,
Android developer

Comment: Add a catch block and log the exception and then post it here

Comment: Hi, This is the exception logged->
The exception in measure....null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:403)
.activity.HomeScreenActivty.getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(HomeScreenActivty.java:424)

Comment: I could figure out why i was getting npe.
I was using BaseAdapter earlier instead of using Arrayadapter.
Now I m using-
ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter ) listview.getAdapter();
and also use Arrayadapter constructor which takes in the layout resource id like this : 
listAdapterArray = new ListItemsArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.listviewitem, itemList);
shoppingItemList.setAdapter(listAdapterArray);
 and then call the above mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

In the list view, at any time, only the visible children are actually created. Therefore, you need to update children which aren't created yet in the getView method of your adapter. If you'd like to update the children which are currently visible, you can traverse through the visible children of the list view. Here's a sample code to do that:

```
for(int k = 0; k<listView.getChildCount(); k++){
     View child = listView.getChildAt(k);

     // For demo purposes, here I'm just updating a textview, you can do whatever you want
     TextView demo = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.demo_text_view);
     demo.setText("demo");
}
```