# How to create PDF of using content of activity in android?

Tags: android

I have create an app of payroll system in android and it needs to be save the salary slip in PDF format that's why i need to create pdf of using content from SalarySlip.java.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-an-android-app

Comment: You can create pdf file by inserting content to some pdf file. I provide you the reference from where you can get the idea of how to generate pdf http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Blog/post/2012/06/15/Generating-PDFs-Dynamically-on-Android.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For devices with API level 19 or more you can use the built in **[PrintedPdfDocument](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html)**.

> This class is a helper for creating a PDF file for given print attributes. It is useful for implementing printing via the native Android graphics APIs.

```
// open a new document
PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context,printAttributes);

// start a page
Page page = document.startPage(0);

// draw something on the page
View content = getContentView();
content.draw(page.getCanvas());

// finish the page
document.finishPage(page);
. . .
// add more pages
. . .
// write the document content
document.writeTo(getOutputStream());

//close the document
document.close();
```

For more advance Features use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/api)