# Android Print HTML Document

Tags: android

I'm new into Android development and stuck with [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) and [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Custom_Document_Printing_Tutorial)

Basically, I want to print a web page into a PDF. But when using the documentation I'm getting error with `getActivity()` function.

And in the second link (the tutorial) I'm getting error with `PlaceholderFragment()`.

Could anyone give me a complete example to print a HTML Page?

I also want to know what a fragment is? Should I create a fragment to make the code work? And how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Android App is structured to have many components: activities, fragments, services, adapters, models and your controller/business classes.

Each component `extends` a specific android class.
For example, activities extends `Activity` class or `AppCompatActivity` class.
Fragment can extend `Fragment` class, Service extends `Service` class, and so on...

There are some methods that can only be used in activity because they are `Activity` class methods (or ascendant).

So if you need to use the `getActivity()` method, that can be used by a Fragment, but you are not in a fragment, you need to get the activity in some other way.

For example:

```
private void doWebViewPrint() {
    WebView webView = new WebView(getActivity());
}
```

should become:

```
private void doWebViewPrint(Activity activity) {
    WebView webView = new WebView(activity);
}
```

and you have to call it from an activity calling:

```
webprinter.doWebViewPrint(this);
```

or even better:

```
private void doWebViewPrint(Context context) {
    WebView webView = new WebView(context);
}
```

and you have to call it from an activity calling:

```
webprinter.doWebViewPrint(getApplicationContext());
```

In the second link you wrote, I can't find any mention to PlaceholderFragment.

By the way, it is not mandatory to use fragments in your app, you can just use activities for having a working app. Fragments are useful for managing different "views" in a same container of an activities, for example when using a navigation drawer, they have their own lifecycle and can be attached and detached without changing activity.

You can find more information on how to Print HTML to PDF [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4565602/6548766).