# editText and generating pdf in android studio

Tags: android, pdf, android-edittext

I am creating a proposal form for my app user to fill out by entering texts in EditText and print them out in an external pdf that will then be generated out
how may i go about this?

Comment: Please ask specific questions related to code and not general questions.

Comment: What you did till now?

Comment: This question has already been asked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-an-android-app

Comment: Apologies H.Brooks i could n't find it. Thanks Let me check it out.

Comment: http://valokafor.com/fill-pdf-form-in-android/  I found this online, I already have the fillable form pdf, my proposal form has 5 pages, I would like to enter data and print it back on the pdf form on my app. Kindly help, I am new to android.