# Print image or pdf from Android App without google cloud printer, Need Silent Printer

Tags: java, android, printing

I know this type of questions asked several times on Stackoverflow, but i didn't get any satisfactory answer for the same.
So my question is can we print file(image or pdf) from our own android app without searching available printer and by just giving SSID or name of printer???
Do HP provides Open source printing sdk for android developers?, Because i searched on HP Print SDK on HP Developer site, they providing link but it is not working.
TYI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create PDFs in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-an-android-app)

Comment: @ImAtWar That question is for generating pdf, in my app i have already generated file just i have to print it without showing any popup or dialog to select printer...

Comment: Share some code please, as far as i know all you would need is to download it and store it. You wouldnt need a 'printer' for it.

Comment: i have saved it in my internal storage, I have used PrintHelper, but it shows up dialog to select printer. I just want silent printer in android

Comment: Print that image or pdf is the main function of my app.

Comment: Are you trying to print over a Bluetooth printer?

Comment: @Naz141 No, Over wifi printer