# how to create report PDF or Excel from sever in andorid?

Tags: php, android, mysql, fpdf

i want to create report pdf or excel from server data, i'm using PHP MYSQL and android, how i can create the report in android? somebody can help me to give example codes, or reference to create it?

thanks u so much !!

regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create PDFs in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-an-android-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: if i create form android to pdf it's oke and i was try and running well, but i want get file pdf like report using fpdf or etc,,

Comment: check https://dito.online